# PivotTable connection timeout was exceeded

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, pivot-table

I am creating a PivotTable in excel and pulling data from SSAS multidimensional cube, however when I select a measure to be shown in PivotTable then OLAP query runs in the background for 60 seconds and then it throws following error:

> The Connection timeout was exceeded

I've increased Analysis server property `ExternalConnectionTimeout` from 60 to 180 but even then my PivotTable throws same error after 60 seconds.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'd guess Excel may also have a limit. Other questions are: Is this happening when you try and pull in a measure into a blank pivot? How many rows of data does the Fact have in it? Do you have an Aggregation Design Built?

Comment: I was missing 'Timeout' and 'Connect Timeout' properties in excel connection string. I configured these properties in excel connection string and got the results. Thanks for help..